# How to make this MySQL query using variables to work?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli

I have a form which sends a Roll_No value using post method to a php file:

```
//Query the database
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM late WHERE 'Roll_No' LIKE '" . $_POST['Roll_No'] . "';");

//Count the returned rows
if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){  

//Turn the results into an array and echo them
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $Roll_No = $rows['Roll_No'];
        $Time = $rows['Time'];

        echo "<p>Roll_No: $Roll_No <br />Time: $Time</p>";
    }
```

My code seems to be unable to take the Roll_No value from the form and therefore gives no results.

EDIT: Here's the form

```
<form action="report-d1.php" method="post" />
<p>Search by Roll_No<input type="text" name="Roll_No" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: stop, putting raw user generated variables in to your query will get you hacked faster than I can say  arggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: Check first if $_POST isset .

Comment: .. why LIKE and not **=**

Comment: Hi, @Sluppo! Use at least `[*_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)` and try to use `%` before or after, or both when binding your `Roll_no` variable to your query. And I'm not sure about the `;` inside your query. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: sidenote: identifier quotes are backticks

Comment: @Ghost - oh yeah, forgot about that one. Nice observation

Comment: @Dagon How else can I go about doing this then? I only started doing this a week ago, I did not know of PHP or MySQL until then. Also yes I tried using = but that gave the same result so I tried using LIKE afterwards.

Comment: is your form even using post?

Comment: @cpugourou Checked, yes it's set.

Comment: @Dagon Yes it is, I even checked if $_POST isset and it is.

Comment: add the form to the question

Comment: @Dagon For some reason the html code is not getting displayed, even if I limit the code to the <form> </form> block.

Comment: @Dagon I'm sorry I tried it now and it worked, was in a hurry to go to college earlier. The form is in the question now.

Comment: Which type has the Roll_No in your table?

Comment: @ManuelBecker It's of the type varchar.